# Getting surfaceview's height and width while implementing runnable

Tags: android, surfaceview, runnable

I've read many threads here which discuss how to get view size at runtime yet none of the solutions have worked for me.

**GameScreen.java**

```
public class GameScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

// Declare an instance of SnakeView
GameView snakeView;

SurfaceHolder surface;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

    snakeView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.GameView);
    surface = snakeView.getHolder();

    snakeView = new GameView(this, surface);

}
```

where GameView is a view class extending surfaceview. The following is a simplified version of my code detailing the issue. I've omitted the run() method and many others to avoid confusion.

**GameView.java**

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public GameView(Context context,  AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}


public GameView(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {

    super(context);
    init();

    m_context = context;

    // Initialize the drawing objects
    m_Holder = surfaceholder;
    m_Paint = new Paint();
}

private void init(){
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }


        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                                   int format, int width, int height) {
         m_Screenheight = height;
         m_Screenwidth = width;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

However calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` causes the app to crash.

I know that you have to wait for the view to layout but I've tried all the suggestions but I've tried all the suggestions from other threads to no avail.

My main lack of understanding comes from the fact that I am using implements Runnable in my custom class so I'm not sure where I am allowed to use getWidth or a similar method. I'm new to android in general so please be explicit in your solution.

EDIT:

I should mention that I am using the width and height to form a grid to draw in the surfaceview.

EDIT 2:

See revised code.

Comment: you have `surfaceChanged()` method which passes the data you want

Comment: So should i use getWidth() within surfaceChanged()?

Comment: `surfaceChanged` takes 4 parameters, use them

Comment: I've edited my original code with an attempt to use surfaceChanged but it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

If your surface is full screen, you can get the screen sizes.

```
public GameView(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {

    super(context);
    init();

    m_context = context;

    // Initialize the drawing objects
    m_Holder = surfaceholder;
    m_Paint = new Paint();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity)context).getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay()
            .getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    m_ScreenHeight= height;
    m_ScreenWidth= width;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my view is not full screen. Its in a linear layout on the screen